# Java Thread checkAccess

Tags: java, android

I was pondering, playing around with some code. I came across the following method in the Thread class: `checkAccess()`.

The documentation (literally) says *"Does nothing."* Why would this possibly be in the Thread class if it does nothing? - Are we possibly dealing with developer trolls?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Or maybe troll developers? =p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.checkAccess()` is from core Java APIs so that's why it exists in `Android` as well, however it is not implemented.

Android's [java.lang.Thread.checkAccess()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#checkAccess%28%29) doesn't provide this implementation because it is not trusting [SecurityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/SecurityManager.html)s.

> > Security managers do not provide a secure environment for executing untrusted code. Untrusted code cannot be safely isolated within the Dalvik VM.

And this is how `Thread.checkAccess` is implemented inside OpenJDK.

```
public final void checkAccess() {
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkAccess(this);
    }
}
```